# Drupal Media, nginx proxy to apache, getting 502 Bad Request for progress-bar

Tags: apache, nginx, drupal, drupal-7

i´m have migrated a Drupal site to my server,

the server uses nginx to do ssl-termination and let apache do the rest, e.g nginx works as a proxy.

However, using the Drupal Media-Browser to upload a file, i´m getting a "502 Bad Gateway" error for requesting `/file/progress/xyz` (i guess it´s the progress-bar) the actual file-upload works though.

this is the nginx server block for the site:

```
server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name  www.example.com;
  port_in_redirect off;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/xyz.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/xyz.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
  ssl_session_timeout 60m;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  location / {
    gzip_static on;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";

    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;

  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

and this is my proxy.conf

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_buffering Off;
proxy_buffers           32 4m;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     25m;
proxy_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
client_max_body_size        1024m;
client_body_buffer_size     4m;
proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
proxy_send_timeout 300s;
proxy_intercept_errors off;
```

i also tried adding this to the http block of nginx.conf

```
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 10m;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

with no success, so i basically tried everything I found on the web regarding this topic with no success, i´m pretty new to nginx though, so maybe i am just overseeing sth?

Nginx logs to error_log:

```
2019/05/15 08:09:26 [error] 21245#0: *42 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 55.10.229.62, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /file/progress/190432132829 HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/file/progress/190432132829", 
host: "www.example.com", 
referrer: "https://www.example.com/media/browser?render=media-popup&options=Uusog2IwkXxNr-0EaqD1L6-Y0aBHQVunf-k4J1oUb_U&plugins="
```

So maybe it´s because upstream is http?

What makes me worry even more is that I get a segfault logged in httpd-error_log

```
[core:notice] [pid 21277] AH00052: child pid 21280 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I have the latest Drupal-7.67 core and all modules are uptodate

using PHP 7.2.17 on a CENTOS7 
with nginx 1:1.12.2-2.el7
and httpd 2.4.6-88.el7.centos

i also added this to drupal´s settings.php

```
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = ['127.0.0.1'];
```

but it doesn´t seem to have any effect

Update:

for beeing complete on this one, here are the details of the failing request (from chrome network-tab)

Response Headers

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 575
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 15 May 2019 06:09:26 GMT
Server: nginx/1.12.2
```

Request Headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _pk_ses.10.9e92=1; has_js=1; cookie-agreed=2; SSESS812a016a321fb8affaf4=pY3nnqqagiCksF61R45R6Zrmi6g6DdMcYRxSPM1HLP0; Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=0; _pk_id.10.9e92=614e315e332df7.1557898005.1.1557900255.1557898005.
Host: www.example.com
Referer: https://www.example.com/media/browser?render=media-popup&options=Uusog2IwkXxNr-0EaqD1L6-Y0aBHQVunf-k4J1oUb_U&plugins=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

when I remove the php pecl-uploadprogress

```
yum remove php-pecl-uploadprogress.x86_64
```

the error is gone, but the progress-bar is not working then, even though i have apc. On the [Pecl-uploadprogress page](https://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) they mention that other SAPI implementations, than apache with mod_php only unfortunately still have issues. 
I guess i ran into one of these,
however i would highly approchiate to let Apache report the progress.

Comment: Are you using varnish ?

Comment: I´m not running any varnish before or in between

Comment: hum.. i don't have idea but i found this link about pecl upload and drupal , it can bring some help https://www.drupal.org/node/793264 in General Requirements

Comment: Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: There are many libraries involved unfortunatly i cant tell which update did fix it, probably php and pecl,  also on drupal8+ i never ran into this again ... sry